# Circular background for toolbar icons

Tags: android, android-layout

is there a way to add a background to the toolbar icons,
I want to achieve this design 
[image]

or there is another way to do it. since it has the overflow icon

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***complete reference code***
this is the result[image]

1. add the following in your app theme or activity style to make it `NoActionBar` activity

   ```
       <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
       <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
   ```
2. add the toolbar in your `activity.xml` and customize the view as you like

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme">                     

   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width ="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">
       <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/back_arrow"
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
           android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
           android:layout_centerVertical="true"
           android:background="@drawable/cir_shape"
           android:onClick="clickBack"
           android:padding="6dp"
           android:visibility="visible"
           app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_back_black_24dp"
           tools:ignore="VectorDrawableCompat" />

       <LinearLayout
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:background="@drawable/rect_shape"
           android:gravity="center"
           android:orientation="horizontal"
           android:padding="3dp">

           <ImageView
               android:id="@+id/app_bar_image"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:scaleType="centerInside"
               android:visibility="visible"
               android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
               app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_visibility_black_24dp"
               android:layout_marginEnd="3dp" />

           <TextView
               android:id="@+id/app_bar_text"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="match_parent"
               android:layout_gravity="center"
               android:gravity="center"
               android:text="1.3K"
               android:textAllCaps="false"
               android:textColor="@color/whiteColor"
               android:textSize="18sp"
               android:textStyle="bold"
               android:visibility="visible" />


       </LinearLayout>
   </RelativeLayout>
   ```

3.add the support action bar as the `toolbar` in the `MainActivity.java` in `OnCreate()`

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    if (toolbar != null) {
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    }
```

4.the `circle_shape.xml` in the drawable for arrow_back drawable

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="oval">
        <solid android:color="#95686566" />
    </shape>
```

5.the `rectangle_shape.xml` in the drawable

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="#95686566" />
    </shape>
```

6.for customizing the 3 dots(overflow icon) add

```
<item  name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/ThreeDotsStyle</item>
```

the in your `style.xml` main theme

```
     <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->        
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/ThreeDotsStyle</item>
</style>
```

and create it's theme

```
 <style name="ThreeDotsStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
        <item name="android:src">@drawable/my_threedots_menu</item>
    </style>
```

7.the `my_threedots_menu.xml`

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape android:shape="oval">
            <solid android:color="#95686566" />
            <padding
                android:bottom="5dp"
                android:left="5dp"
                android:right="5dp"
                android:top="5dp" />
        </shape>

    </item>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_menu_dots"
        android:gravity="center" />

</layer-list>
```

8.inflate your menu

```
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.my_menu, menu);
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create container with custom background inside `Toolbar`, put `ImageView` inside and add some padding to it for example:

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/middle_background">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_arrow_forward_white_24" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Background `middle_background.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/resandroid"
android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/holo_orange_dark" />
</shape>
```

Adjust padding, `ImageView` to get desired look but basically you will have something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom toolbar and put your custom icons inside of it.

```
  <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
app:theme="@style/myCustomAppBarTheme"
app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <!-- your custom icons goes here -->
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

1) ***btn_ripple_background***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:state_enabled="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/ripple_circular_shape"/>
</selector>
```

2) ***ripple_circuler_shape***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="@color/btn_state_pressed_text_color"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@color/btn_state_pressed_text_color" />
</shape>
```

Finally `android:foreground="@drawable/ripple_btn_background"`